# How to print every other number?

Tags: java

I am new to java, just started learning the basics concepts of it, I am now trying to develop a program where users enter two numbers and the program prints every other number between these two numbers, I have tried several methods but I just can grasp how to do it, I know this might seem really easy, but I have been spending the past two days trying to figure it out with no luck at all. I would really appreciate any help. I manage to write the code enabling the inputs of values but after that, it is just blank, and I am not able to proceed:/

This is how far I came with my code which is probably way off.

```
public class EveryOther {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int FirstNumber = 0;
    int SecondNumber = 0;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("FirstNumber: " );
    scanner.nextInt();

    Scanner scanner2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Second Number: ");
    scanner.nextInt(); {

        while (FirstNumber <= SecondNumber + 2);
        System.out.println(SecondNumber * FirstNumber +2);
        SecondNumber++;

    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's way off. You don't assign anything to the two variables, your `while` does nothing, because there's semicolon right after it and the math is also wrong. You should also name your variables in lowercase. This code is beyond help, you should read something on the basics of Java.

Comment: You are almost there. Just think a little bit about when the `while` loop is going to exit and how can you achieve that by changing values of `FirstNumber` or `SeconNumber`.

Comment: Do you want to print `System.out.println(SecondNumber * FirstNumber +2)` ? Both numbers multiplied and addition of 2 ?

Comment: in your question you said you want to print other numbers between  range of 2 readd numbers but in your code your trying to myltiply first with second ?

Comment: first, look at @beginner_coder's objection regarding `;`, that's just a syntax mistake. Then, try to step through the code in your head: what are `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` at every line? Are your variables progressing in the direction you want?

Comment: You're trying to solve the whole task at once and that's not how it's done. Try to break it into smaller subtasks: (1) write a program where users enters one number and the program prints it; (2) same as (1) for two numbers; (3) write a program that prints numbers from 1 to 10 using loop. Once you have working code for subtasks, you can combine them.

Comment: I really appreciate the actual constructive responses that can help me learn, as I mentioned I am very new to Java, so my code is a mess, I don't think anyone came out of their mothers with a keyboard writing java so it's ok to make mistakes to learn from. It is a learning curve, but I am really determined to do it. As for my code, I am struggling with understanding how to print a set of numbers between two variables, and how to create that with iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So suppose you have your `firstNumber = 5` and `secondNumber = 10` then every other number starting from `firstNumber` in this case will be `5,7,9` that means you just have to increase `firstNumber's` value `by 2` in **every iteration** of loop. It can be done as follows:

```
while (firstNumber < secondNumber ){
        System.out.println(firstNumber );
        firstNumber = firstNumber + 2;
}
```

Hope it helps you understand.

Answer (score 3):

1. FirstNumber and SecondNumber are assigned to 0, but we actually want to get it assigned from Scanner. here are some useful examples. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_user_input.asp
2. the while loop does nothing because the conditional code is an empty statement. the link might be very helpful. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_while_loop.htm

   ```
   import java.util.Scanner;

   public class EveryOther {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

           int FirstNumber = 0;
           int SecondNumber = 0;

           Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("FirstNumber: " );
           FirstNumber = scanner.nextInt();

           System.out.print("Second Number: ");
           SecondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

           while (FirstNumber < SecondNumber){
               System.out.println(FirstNumber);
               FirstNumber = FirstNumber + 2;
           }
       }
   ```

   }

Comment: this may be the solution, but do you think it will help the OP without any comments on how you did it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi @GTech7 Please check this code with the comments.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Initialize 2 numbers
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Read 1st number
        System.out.print("First Number: " );
        firstNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        // Read 2nd number
        System.out.print("Second Number: ");
        secondNumber = scanner.nextInt();

        if (firstNumber < secondNumber) {
            printAndIncrement(firstNumber, secondNumber);
        } else {
            printAndIncrement(secondNumber, firstNumber);
        }

    }

    private static void printAndIncrement(int smallNo, int largeNo) {
        while (smallNo < largeNo){
            System.out.println(smallNo);
            smallNo = smallNo + 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Do not use 2 Scanners, because you can read any number of inputs using the same Scanner.

Comment: works well, but the part that is tricky for me is how to print out all numbers between the First and the second number, assuming the user will input the Firstnumber > Secondnumber. so if it 20 & 5, the system should print 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, which is mainly the part I am stuck at

Comment: Put an additional condition to check if the first number is greater than the second number you can swap the two.

Comment: Yes, you can put if else like an above-edited code block. Also, you can extract a common method if you want to print and increment the number.

Comment: Please check the above-edited code, It is easy to understand.

Answer (score 1):

As others mentioned here, you might need to read a bit some theory first.

**Learning by Doing** is good after you've reached some milestones in the basic theories. In other words Do Not Jump in the middle of any programming language, if you intent to become a good developer and be able to work with other professionals . Java and its underlying concept (OOP) need to be understood well in many ways first. Then its versatile APIs will help a professional developer to not re-invent the wheel in complex projects. For instance using [Java Streams](https://winterbe.com/posts/2014/07/31/java8-stream-tutorial-examples/) (after reading the input and assigning it to variables correctly!) will nail this task in the safest and cleanest way:

*btw, i can't understand how multiplying `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` and + 2 and the end is gonna fulfill the following intention:

> users enter two numbers and the program prints every other number between these two numbers

based on my interpretation of the quote above:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;


public class EveryOther {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    /* take a look at java naming conventions */
    int firstNumber, secondNumber;

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("FirstNumber: " );
    firstNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    /* No need to make a new instance if Scanner! */
    System.out.print("Second Number: ");
    secondNumber = scanner.nextInt();
    scanner.close();

    IntStream.range(firstNumber + 1, secondNumber).forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a good take, unfortunately, this is a school assignment, and I completely agree with your point, I feel some of these tasks, cant be done until a certain level of theory has been covered but it seems like they assumed we all are at that level to give us such problems that could be hard for someone who is still scratching the surface of java.

Comment: At my school time (as java 8 was new) we were asked to use the smartest possible way via researching and learning API usage. Sometimes looping was forbidden and we had to dive into new features of language! If it's simply an *Algorithmics* assignment, I would go with other languages like Python! Java is too complicated to focus on algo imo

Comment: unfortunately, it is a java class. Which you might have seen, is not going well for me, because we started less than a month ago, and I had no prior experience with programming before, so it is turning into a very stressful class, as I am not comfortable at all with 90% of the fundamentals, so doing these programs is a very challenging experience.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code which need to be corrected:

The while loop is being closed with a ; so the code following is not being executed within a loop.

```java
while (FirstNumber <= SecondNumber + 2) {
    System.out.println(SecondNumber * FirstNumber + 2);
    SecondNumber++;
}
```

- You do not need two scanners as a single scanner should suffice.
- The    values that are being input from the scanners are not being
  assigned    to any variables declared and the loop will print two in
  an infinite    manner.
- The logic within the loop is incorrect as you are    continuously
  changing the upper limit which will make the loop    infinitely
  executing.

Comment: No, this is not what it should be. This is an endless loop which will print `2` for all eternity.

Comment: I am in a process to edit yet could not complete the answer sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I have found most of the comments on here helpful, and I have managed to understand a little bit, I think I wasn't a way of as I thought, just needed your helpful comments to help me understand how to address this problem. Thank you.